# Locked out from Windows Server 2008R2 disk as an Administrator

Tags: security, permissions, windows-server-2008-r2

I've done something stupid. I tried to lock down the access rights to a disk using the security properties at disk level. However, in the process, I've locked myself out as Administrator. I can and have seized ownership of the disk, and then I can view the security properties of the disk. Howver if I try to edit and change them for administrators I get "An error occured while applying security information to: E:\  Access Denied". UAC is set to never notify. The disk is also inaccessable with an elevated command prompt. Same message "Access Denied".

Security settings as follows:
CREATOR OWNER - No settings
SYSTEM - All deny
MY_USERNAME - All allow
Administrators - All allow
Users - All deny

I guess I cannot get access because I am in the users group. Can I solve this without removing myself from the Users group? I prefer not to do that because it is an Active Directory group in the Users group which I am in over which I have no control.

Comment: You should be able to take ownership over the object. Once you do that, you can set the ACL to whatever you want.

Comment: Okay. What I hoped I didn't have to do worked. 1. Remove the AD group 'Authenticated Users' from the local machine Users group. 2. Set rights for Users as an adminsitrator and owner to access. 3. Add Authenticated Users back to the local machine Users group.

No other way out in this dead-lock.

Comment: **Deny ACLs take precedence over allow ACLs.**  If you have a DENY all, then you will never be able to access anything.  **You should almost never be using an explicit DENY ACL** on Windows.  Simply don't add acls that allow access, and depend on the implicit deny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. What I hoped I didn't have to do worked. 
1. Remove the AD group 'Authenticated Users' from the local machine Users group.
2. Set rights for Users as an adminsitrator and owner to access.
3. Add Authenticated Users back to the local machine Users group.

No other way out in this dead-lock.